# how to backup only files paths, names, sizes and checksums?

Tags: windows-7, backup, filenames, checksum

I'm looking for an application which will allow me to select some folders, and then regularly backup only complete paths, names, sizes and checksums of the files within those folders and their subfolders.

I'm using Windows 7 x64.

Comment: you might want to reword your statement to refer `audit` requirements rather than `backup` -- which implies storing the data rather than tracking its change.

Comment: Well, I don't really want to track changes. I've recently noticed that during my backups lots of files which are downloadable from the Internet get backed up and takes space. I don't really need the files themselves, only data about them which will allow me to download them if they get deleted.

Comment: in that case all you need is a directory listing that can be used to derive the source reference. You could also consider maintaining a separate file with the URLs which you backup (check download logs maybe?).

Answer (score 1):

Update: based on your comment in the question.
The `find` command listing with checksum I give below will give you the checksum detail. 
But, if you can work w/o the checksum part, a plain `dir /s` listing from Windows 7 command prompt saved to a file will give you good information.
<sup>I'll still go ahead to install Cygwin and use basic shell scripting to process information -- good flexibility there.</sup>

---

The word `backup` is a misdirection here.
What you seem to want is an audit tool that will keep track of your Windows directory contents for (maybe) tampering; I sense a security or management audit purpose.

For a long while there used to be a free tool called *Tripwire* for such things.
These days there is an [open-source version available at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/).

There is [AFICK (Another File Integrity Checker)](http://afick.sourceforge.net/) on SourceForge which might work for you.

If you are fine with some scripting, you can run a `SHA1` (for speed) check on a file list generated by `find` in Cygwin or some such. Or, just write a Perl/Python/Ruby/PowerShell script for yourself. This might not perform too well (compared to low-level solutions like Tripwire) but will work for you if your directory tree is not too deep.

Comment: I was hoping for some software rather than using the command line. Since my directory tree is pretty deep and there's a lot of files, performance is an important issue. Listing files using the command line takes a bit too long.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CD Collection](http://web.archive.org/web/20120103191609/http://www.nicomsoft.com/cdc/) by nicomsoft. It works with folders too.

Comment: It doesn't save any checksums and doesn't support special characters (eg. japanese kanji) in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.

I made [pyFileFixity](https://github.com/lrq3000/pyFileFixity/), a self-contained Python 2 library, [containing the tool "rfigc.py"](https://github.com/lrq3000/pyFileFixity/#recursive-relative-files-integrity-generator-and-checker-in-python-aka-rfigc). It works on all platforms, and the databases generated on one OS can be used on other OSes (because paths are relative and always uniformized in UNIX style).

I am running Windows 7 x64, the same as you, and I am using the library regularly, so you should be safe with it. It is also unit tested on Travis (running Linux), so I know it also works on *nix OSes.